# Unable to disconnect deployment center for Azure function App

Tags: azure-functions, continuous-deployment, cicd

The disconnect option in the deployment centre is missing, any thoughts?

Tried this command to disconnect, but no changes whatsoever
"az webapp deployment source delete --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup"

[image]

Comment: same here, this az cli does not work if use azure pipelines

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your requirement in my environment, and I could see the ***disconnect*** option.

- Created function app and configured deployment source by choosing *Azure Repos* as *Source*.
- Go to function app> Deployment Center>I can see the ***Disconnect*** option inside Settings section.

[image]

And also, I have used below mentioned AZ CLI command to delete the deployment source from function app and to check whether its deleted or not:

```
az webapp deployment source delete --name <function-app-name> --resource-group <Resource-group-Name>
az webapp deployment source show --name pravufuncapp --resource-group pravufuncapp_group
```

[image]

As it can be seen below, deployment source got disconnected and redirected to the deployment source page:

[image]

Comment: there is a difference. We are not setting the CICD from the deployment centre. The function app is created using an ARM template and functions are deployed as run from package via the azure devops pipeline.